# How do you resolve Linked server references in SQL Database project in VS?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, tfs, database-project

In a Visual Studio SQL Server Database project, how can you resolve the errors associated with linked server references within the project?

Comment: What kind of errors are you getting?

Answer (score 2):

Trying using [synonyms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177544.aspx) for linked databases.

Comment: How would that help? If the original poster is having the same problem I'm seeing, I think the statement to add a synonym would create a build error in the Visual Studio project.